# Why onClick is not rendered for html a?

Tags: reactjs

Have following code:

```
<a
  className={"a_2"}
  onClick={() => {
    alert(
```

But final HTML contains no `onclick`, why?

```
<a class="a_2"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

React's events are what are known as [`Synthetic Events`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of `SyntheticEvent`, a
> cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the
> same interface as the browser’s native event, including
> `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`, except the events work
> identically across all browsers.

In other words, react does not map exactly to plain HTML and JavaScript because most of the dom manipulation is handled in the React DOM ([VDOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html)) rather than by the browser's regular DOM.

Comment: Shouldn't in `<a>` any handler? I press the `a` and nothing happens. Shall I use a `button` instead?

Comment: actually, it happens but refreshing and can see it by stopping default behavior

Comment: If I replace a to button, still no onclick is in the element, why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `button` also you can use `<a>` like

```
<a
  className={"a_2"}
   onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Your alert message");
      }
   }
></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) :

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a
> cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the
> same interface as the browser’s native event, including
> stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work
> identically across all browsers.

The default behavior of an anchor is to refresh the page, must prevent default behavior with :

```
e.preventDefault()
```

also can remove the `href` or use `href='javascript:void(0)'`

so anchor tag can use this way:

```
<a
  className={"a_2"}
   onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("message");
      }
   }
></a>
```

or

```
const callMe = ()=>{
alert("message")
}
  <a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick={callMe}>
              some text
            </a>
```

for seeing events can use the Event Listeners tab under the Elements tab in the developer tools

[image]

Comment: I see, basically I need here not `<a>` but `<button>`. Or not? Strange, if I replace a to button, still no onclick is in the element, why?

Comment: I think using button is cleaner in your need

Comment: @János events are not in elements. must see it in the event listener tab